# oracle installation error ORA-12638

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, installation

I get ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed error while installing oracle. 
Most of forums gave solution by changing SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) To: - SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE) in sqlnet.ora

But, doing this I get ORA-1031: INSUFFICIENT PRIVILEGES while connecting AS SYSDBA

Comment: Do you connect to the DB using sqlplus on the same server where the database is installed?

Comment: Yes I connect to the DB using sqlplus on the same server where the database is installed

Comment: Then you use OS authentification to access the DB, can you try to enter the DB as sysdba with the same OS user as the Oracle DB owner.

Comment: Also is this Linux/Unix or Windows OS?

Comment: This is windows OS and right now while installing I am getting this error ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed error.. how should i proceed installation

Comment: You could put SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE) but this disables Windows native security. Alternative would be to create OS role called ORA_DBA and assign it to the OS user with which you connect to DB.

Comment: In this way you should be able to connect with that OS user as sysdba to the database.